# How to make a jagged array neat in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array like this: `['a', ['e', 'r', 't'], 'c']`.

I want to use some sort of processing to make the array neat:
`[['a', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'r', 'c'], ['a', 't', 'c']]`.

If the array is: `['a', ['e', 'r', 't'], ['c', 'd']]`.

The result is:
`[['a', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'e', 'd'], ['a', 'r', 'c'], ['a', 'r', 'd'], ['a', 't', 'c'], ['a', 't', 'd']]`.

And the length of the array is not fixed to 3, other examples:

```
['a', 'b'] = > ['a', 'b']
['a', ['b', 'c']] => [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c']]
['ab', ['b', 'c']] => [['ab', 'b'], ['ab', 'c']]
[[1, 2], 3, 4] => [[1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

So what should I do? Is there a solution in Numpy?

Comment: What's the expected output for - `['a', ['e', 'r', 't'], ['b', 'c']]`?

Comment: Is the depth consistent ? What about `['a', ['e', 'r', ['t', 'y']], 'c']`

Comment: did you mean that you want to convert some elements to a list and add to them things later?

Comment: Thanks, I modified my question, the highest depth is 2.@Divakar @Bck

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at the expected output?

Comment: Shouldn't the output of the second example be - `[['a', 'e', 'c'], ['a', 'e', 'd'], ['a', 'r', 'c'], ['a', 'r', 'd'], ['a', 't', 'c'], ['a', 't', 'd']]` ?

Comment: @TomRon, thanks, i modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the question, you just want the [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of the sub-lists, although you have to wrap any single elements into lists first.

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> arr = ['a', ['e', 'r', 't'], ['c', 'd']]
>>> listified = [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in arr]
>>> listified
[['a'], ['e', 'r', 't'], ['c', 'd']]
>>> list(product(*listified))
[('a', 'e', 'c'),
 ('a', 'e', 'd'),
 ('a', 'r', 'c'),
 ('a', 'r', 'd'),
 ('a', 't', 'c'),
 ('a', 't', 'd')]
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is **neat** way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a recursive solution:

```
inlist1 = ['ab', ['e', 'r', 't'], ['c', 'd']]
inlist2 = [['a', 'b'], ['e', 'r', 't'], ['c', 'd']]
inlist3 = [['a', 'b'], 'e', ['c', 'd']]


def jagged(inlist):
    a = [None] * len(inlist)

    def _jagged(index):
        if index == 0:
            print(a)
            return
        v = inlist[index - 1]
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for i in v:
                a[index - 1] = i
                _jagged(index - 1, )
        else:
            a[index - 1] = v
            _jagged(index - 1)

    _jagged(len(inlist))


jagged(inlist3)
```